# Having error when using list in dictionary

Tags: python

I declared these two dictionaries.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

switches_path = {'s1': [], 's2': [], 's3': [], 's4': []}
adjs = {'s1': [s2, s4], 's2': [s1, s3], 's3': [s2, s4], 's4': [s1, s3]}
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t.py", line 7, in <module>
    adjs = {'s1': [s2, s4], 's2': [s1, s3], 's3': [s2, s4], 's4': [s1, s3]}
NameError: name 's2' is not defined
```

I don't understand what's wrong in `'s2'` when it says `not defined`!

Comment: Yep, it's not. Why is that surprising?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `s2` to be? Do you understand that you're creating a dictionary with string keys?

Comment: What is `s2` be? Note you did not put it between quotes, etc. nor did you define a variable with that name.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you mean this?

```
switches_path = {'s1': [], 's2': [], 's3': [], 's4': []}
adjs = {'s1': ['s2', 's4'], 's2': ['s1', 's3'], 's3': ['s2', 's4'], 's4': ['s1', 's3']}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but indeed s2 is not defined as a variable. 's2' is only in use as a key to your two dictionaries, which is not the same as defining a variable.